# Creating Excel file in Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application, excel-interop

I have a C# console application and it is creating excel file and send mail to our customer.

It's working in test server but its not working in production server and we get this following error ;

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
```

I did not find any solution for this error.

We're creating excel file like this and this code fire an error ;

```
_appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

Anyone help me about this situation ? Thanks !

Comment: Have you installed office or excel on your production server?

Comment: Yes , we have office.